# ASP.NET Core Web API can not return results extracted using EF Core lazy-loading

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am exploring EF Core lazy-loading, but struggling to return the results over ASP.NET Web API. Please check my API call below.

```
// GET: api/Supplier
[HttpGet("/GetSupplierUsingLazyLoading")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Supplier>> GetSupplierUsingLazyLoading()
{
    var products = _context.Products.ToList();
    var supplier = products.Last().Supplier;

    return await Task.FromResult(supplier);
    //return await Task.FromResult(new Supplier());
}
```

Yes. I have added the package [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies/)

And I have added `UseLazyLoadingProxies` in my `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddDbContext<NorthwindContext>(
        options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Northwind_MySQL"), Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.Parse("8.0.23-mysql"));
            options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
            options.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);
        }
    );
```

I am using [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/) as database provider.

When I call the Web API from swagger then it makes lot of database calls behind the scenes. This is what I see in the terminal. It keeps on making these call. I had to stop the application to stop these calls. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Is anyone else facing this issue?

```
info: 6/26/2021 08:01:55.859 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `o`.`OrderDetailsID`, `o`.`Discount`, `o`.`OrderID`, `o`.`ProductID`, `o`.`Quantity`, `o`.`UnitPrice`
      FROM `orderdetails` AS `o`
      WHERE `o`.`OrderID` = @__p_0
info: 6/26/2021 08:01:55.863 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `o`.`OrderDetailsID`, `o`.`Discount`, `o`.`OrderID`, `o`.`ProductID`, `o`.`Quantity`, `o`.`UnitPrice`
      FROM `orderdetails` AS `o`
      WHERE `o`.`OrderID` = @__p_0
info: 6/26/2021 08:01:55.867 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `o`.`OrderDetailsID`, `o`.`Discount`, `o`.`OrderID`, `o`.`ProductID`, `o`.`Quantity`, `o`.`UnitPrice`
      FROM `orderdetails` AS `o`
      WHERE `o`.`OrderID` = @__p_0
info: 6/26/2021 08:01:55.870 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `o`.`OrderDetailsID`, `o`.`Discount`, `o`.`OrderID`, `o`.`ProductID`, `o`.`Quantity`, `o`.`UnitPrice`
      FROM `orderdetails` AS `o`
      WHERE `o`.`OrderID` = @__p_0
info: 6/26/2021 08:01:55.876 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `o`.`OrderDetailsID`, `o`.`Discount`, `o`.`OrderID`, `o`.`ProductID`, `o`.`Quantity`, `o`.`UnitPrice`
      FROM `orderdetails` AS `o`
      WHERE `o`.`OrderID` = @__p_0
```

When I use `return await Task.FromResult(new Supplier());` then it returns an empty supplier.

Thanks
Curious Drive

Comment: Try mapping the entity manually or with a mapper (like AutoMapper) to a plain object to forcibly fetch the relations before returning the result to the client. i.e. Use a DTO

Comment: Unrelated: you can simply return the result in an async function, or `return Task.FromResult(val)`, you don't need to `await Task.FromResult(val)`

Comment: Interesting... I tried accessing one of the properties of supplier (i.e. CompanyName) and returned that in a different Object and it worked. It seems like it can't return the virtual property itself. I will have to copy it in something before returning?

Comment: Yes, you have to try to access it before it tries to query the data from the database.

Comment: Hmmm.... That was a curveball. Anyways, thanks for commenting. It's working now.

Comment: As for the excessive DB calls, ASP.NET Core might be trying to navigate endlessly between Product -> Supplier -> Products -> Supplier. There's an option to ignore navigation properties. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization

Comment: Why did you enable lazy loading? It's not something to enable without a very good reason. Esp. in a web application I don't see how it is useful. In a stateful/connected client application it *may* be useful.

Comment: I am actually make a video series about my experience with EF Core. You can check my YouTube Channel here - https://www.youtube.com/c/curiousdrive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Remember that Lazy-Loading is a feature that will only retrieve the data from database when needed and should be used very carefully.

With this in mind, let's talk about your models.
Let's consider that you have a `Supplier`. This suppliers must be connect with some `Orders` as you always buys something from a supplier, right? All `Orders` have `OrderItems` and each of this items are related to a `Product`. So we end with a model graph like this:

[image]

Your classes should look like this

```
public class Supplier
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public  class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order 
{
    public decimal FinalPrice { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

When you try to serialize a Supplier coming from the database, it will also serialize its `Orders`, then the `OrderItems` and then finally the `Product` since your full object graph is serialized.

Remember that the data is only retrieved from database when needed? Well, the serializer serializes each node a time, so if you have 4 order items, it will go and asks the database for the 4 products 4 times.

When you serialize a `new Supplier()` this doesn't occurs for 2 reasons. A `new Supplier()` is not tracked by EntityFramework, so no queries are made and even if it was tracked, this supplier has no Orders and thus no additional query will be ran.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. Microsoft docs should be this detailed.

Comment: You're welcome, buddy! How Lazy-Loading + EntityFramework works can be tricky sometimes.